# How to copy specific word or number from cell?

Tags: excel-formula

I have pasted below values which are in a cell, i want to copy only cell numbers from this cell. Please guide how i can do this in excel.

**Cell value:**

"1.  MEMBER ID   2100002-2 PRIME COLOUR TRADING COMPANY STREET# 5, KUTCHERY BAZAR, FAISALABAD TEL :   041-2626573,2622644 MOBILE : 0300-8652090 FAX :   041-2622675"

Regards,
Adnan

Comment: So your output in this example is 0300-8652090? If so, please add that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(A2, 1, FIND("MOBILE : ", A2)+8, TEXT(,)), 13, LEN(A2), TEXT(,))
```